# Как сделать размытие блока в конце,как на макете?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать такое рызмытие,которое в конце блока : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="indexS.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 315px;
        height: 310px;
      }

      /* Скрытие полосы прокрутки в веб-браузерах на основе WebKit */
      .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0.5em;
      }

      .container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      .container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 15px;
      }

      .block {
        width: 140px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 18px;
        background-color: lightgray;
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      .block.visible {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .block:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-right: 10px;
      }

      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container dragscroll">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно использовать линейный градиент

Comment: Создайте псевдоэлемент и сделайте лайнар градиент под нужным углом, один цвет `transparent`, другой `#fff` и сделайте псведоэлемент на весь ваш список элементов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как на половину скрыть блоки слайдера,как на макете?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537822/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @ΝNL993 вы можете сделать это?

Comment: Если конечно не занимает времени