# Как прикрепить линейный градиент вниз

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть вертикальный скролл с 6 блоками :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="indexS.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 315px;
        height: 310px;
      }

      .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0.5em;
      }

      .container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      .container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 15px;
      }

      .block {
        width: 140px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 18px;
        background-color: black;
      }

      .block.visible {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .block:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-right: 10px;
      }

      .container {
        position: relative;
      }

      .container::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);

        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container dragscroll">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Нужно чтобы размытие(линейный градиент) был прикреплён к концу.

Вот как тут :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на сам макет : https://xd.adobe.com/view/3831e990-1d2a-4aa1-9b83-f0ad445abd5d-6d62/screen/412772a8-93d7-425c-a81d-e3e3329ce836/specs/ - там есть этот скролл,который на картинке,который также можно листать.Когда листаешь,то это размытие исчезает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать размытие блока в конце,как на макете?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537837/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)